# Augmenting small datasets for Object Detection with Fully Convolutional Networks

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, object-detection

[This Keras blog](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html) explains nicely, how a small dataset can be augmented by the following code:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=40,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        fill_mode='nearest')
```

I am sure the vanilla example introduced in the blog works well, for similarly simple scenarios.

In a much more complicated scenario, I want to use the weights of models pretrained on the famous [COCO dataset for object detection](http://cocodataset.org/#home), to transfer learn new classes, for which I have only a very limited amount of data (<=1000).

The labeling granularity in such datasets is not per image, but per objects inside the images. I.e., each image may contain one or more objects which are marked by polygonical bounding boxes and these bounding boxes are labeled according to the object names they contain. This complex labeling information is encoded in json format, like in the following example:

```
{
"info": {
    "year": 2018,
    "version": null,
    "description": "Peaches",
    "contributor": "ralph@r4robotics.com.au",
    "url": "labelbox.io",
    "date_created": "2018-04-07T10:08:51.409340+00:00"
},
"images": [{
    "id": "cjfp6vz7xfwz20198ixce9la4",
    "width": 274,
    "height": 184,
    "file_name": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/labelbox-193903.appspot.com/o/cjfp6hjghfuvd01147d130984%2F5a7fdf5d-201a-40d0-bfef-c36d6ed02212%2Fpeach8.jpg?alt=media&token=11337eaa-4ffd-4dfb-b3ec-9c4ee6bd2f17",
    "license": null,
    "flickr_url": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/labelbox-193903.appspot.com/o/cjfp6hjghfuvd01147d130984%2F5a7fdf5d-201a-40d0-bfef-c36d6ed02212%2Fpeach8.jpg?alt=media&token=11337eaa-4ffd-4dfb-b3ec-9c4ee6bd2f17",
    "coco_url": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/labelbox-193903.appspot.com/o/cjfp6hjghfuvd01147d130984%2F5a7fdf5d-201a-40d0-bfef-c36d6ed02212%2Fpeach8.jpg?alt=media&token=11337eaa-4ffd-4dfb-b3ec-9c4ee6bd2f17",
    "date_captured": null
}, {
    "id": "cjfp6wqfhfwyu0107il09db3p",
    "width": 275,
    "height": 183,
    "file_name": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/labelbox-193903.appspot.com/o/cjfp6hjghfuvd01147d130984%2F5a7fdf5d-201a-40d0-bfef-c36d6ed02212%2Fpeach9.jpg?alt=media&token=39dd5e97-c411-43e9-9ba3-9f51a334c7c7",
    "license": null,
    "flickr_url": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/labelbox-193903.appspot.com/o/cjfp6hjghfuvd01147d130984%2F5a7fdf5d-201a-40d0-bfef-c36d6ed02212%2Fpeach9.jpg?alt=media&token=39dd5e97-c411-43e9-9ba3-9f51a334c7c7",
    "coco_url": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/labelbox-193903.appspot.com/o/cjfp6hjghfuvd01147d130984%2F5a7fdf5d-201a-40d0-bfef-c36d6ed02212%2Fpeach9.jpg?alt=media&token=39dd5e97-c411-43e9-9ba3-9f51a334c7c7",
    "date_captured": null
}],
"annotations": [ {
    "id": 23,
    "image_id": "cjfp6vz7xfwz20198ixce9la4",
    "category_id": 1,
    "segmentation": [
        [31.0, 72.0, 63.0, 84.0, 75.0, 105.0, 67.0, 134.0, 68.0, 158.0, 44.0, 174.0, 24.0, 178.0, 2.0, 172.0, 2.0, 82.0, 31.0, 72.0]
    ],
    "area": 6301.0,
    "bbox": [2.0, 6.0, 73.0, 106.0],
    "iscrowd": 0
}, {
    "id": 24,
    "image_id": "cjfp6vz7xfwz20198ixce9la4",
    "category_id": 1,
    "segmentation": [
        [75.0, 103.0, 108.0, 76.0, 137.0, 74.0, 166.0, 89.0, 182.0, 104.0, 188.0, 145.0, 179.0, 171.0, 167.0, 183.0, 92.0, 183.0, 72.0, 158.0, 68.0, 134.0, 75.0, 103.0]
    ],
    "area": 10652.5,
    "bbox": [68.0, 1.0, 120.0, 109.0],
    "iscrowd": 0
}, {
    "id": 25,
    "image_id": "cjfp6vz7xfwz20198ixce9la4",
    "category_id": 1,
    "segmentation": [
        [169.0, 92.0, 182.0, 66.0, 211.0, 53.0, 246.0, 66.0, 262.0, 80.0, 268.0, 95.0, 261.0, 129.0, 241.0, 145.0, 216.0, 153.0, 188.0, 143.0, 184.0, 105.0, 169.0, 92.0]
    ],
    "area": 6838.5,
    "bbox": [169.0, 31.0, 99.0, 100.0],
    "iscrowd": 0
}, {
    "id": 26,
    "image_id": "cjfp6wqfhfwyu0107il09db3p",
    "category_id": 1,
    "segmentation": [
        [86.0, 54.0, 109.0, 56.0, 119.0, 73.0, 113.0, 92.0, 93.0, 101.0, 76.0, 92.0, 70.0, 77.0, 71.0, 63.0, 86.0, 54.0]
    ],
    "area": 1715.0,
    "bbox": [70.0, 82.0, 49.0, 47.0],
    "iscrowd": 0
}, {
    "id": 27,
    "image_id": "cjfp6wqfhfwyu0107il09db3p",
    "category_id": 1,
    "segmentation": [
        [117.0, 95.0, 123.0, 110.0, 136.0, 118.0, 153.0, 113.0, 159.0, 99.0, 158.0, 87.0, 145.0, 79.0, 132.0, 76.0, 123.0, 84.0, 117.0, 95.0]
    ],
    "area": 1260.0,
    "bbox": [117.0, 65.0, 42.0, 42.0],
    "iscrowd": 0
}, {
    "id": 28,
    "image_id": "cjfp6wqfhfwyu0107il09db3p",
    "category_id": 1,
    "segmentation": [
        [109.0, 54.0, 115.0, 40.0, 133.0, 32.0, 146.0, 34.0, 157.0, 43.0, 161.0, 58.0, 152.0, 72.0, 133.0, 76.0, 119.0, 71.0, 109.0, 54.0]
    ],
    "area": 1660.5,
    "bbox": [109.0, 107.0, 52.0, 44.0],
    "iscrowd": 0
}],
"licenses": [],
"categories": [{
    "supercategory": "Peach",
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Peach"
}]
```

}

Obviously, augmentation in this scenario is much more complicated, since  not only the images have to be distorted and rotated, but also the bounding boxes.

Is there any way to do this with Keras?

Answer (score 0):

Though is too late, can you look at these links;

https://github.com/engmubarak48/CLoDSA

https://imgaug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html
https://imgaug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/jupyter_notebooks.html#page-jupyter-notebooks
https://blog.paperspace.com/data-augmentation-for-bounding-boxes/

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Please consult [answer] to read more about how to answer questions

Comment: Thanks Artog, I had limited time, but i will try to edit and give more details.